# Is there any solution to encrypt integer in Django using Django Cryptography

Tags: python, mysql, django, cryptography, migration

I am trying to encrypt Django Integer Choices field using Django Cryptography package, here is the documentation: https://django-cryptography.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html. Here is my code.

```
from django_cryptography.fields import encrypt
 
class NumberOfCars(models.IntegerChoices):
    One_Vehicle = 1
    Two_Vehicle = 2
    Three_To_Four = 4
    Five_To_Eight = 7
    More_than_Eight = 9
 NumberOfCars = encrypt(models.IntegerField(choices=NumberOfCars.choices))
```

I am using Mysql database,
Python==3.10
Django==4.0.4
While running migrations i got this error:

```
    PS C:\Users\lumkile\Desktop\Django\thariauth> py manage.py makemigrations
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\lumkile\Desktop\Django\thariauth\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\lumkile\Desktop\Django\thariauth\manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\lumkile\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\lumkile\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 440, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\lumkile\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 414, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\lumkile\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 455, in execute
    self.check()
  File "C:\Users\lumkile\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 487, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
  File "C:\Users\lumkile\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 88, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "C:\Users\lumkile\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\model_checks.py", line 36, in check_all_models
    errors.extend(model.check(**kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\lumkile\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", 
line 1442, in check
    *cls._check_fields(**kwargs),
  File "C:\Users\lumkile\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", 
line 1554, in _check_fields
    errors.extend(field.check(**kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\lumkile\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django_cryptography\fields.py", line 121, in check
    errors = super().check(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\lumkile\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1931, in check
    *super().check(**kwargs),
  File "C:\Users\lumkile\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 252, in check
    *self._check_validators(),
  File "C:\Users\lumkile\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 413, in _check_validators
    for i, validator in enumerate(self.validators):
  File "C:\Users\lumkile\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 49, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\lumkile\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1954, in validators
    min_value, max_value = connection.ops.integer_field_range(internal_type)
  File "C:\Users\lumkile\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\operations.py", line 673, in integer_field_range
    return self.integer_field_ranges[internal_type]
KeyError: 'BinaryField'
```

I tried to solve this issue by using the solution i found here :https://github.com/georgemarshall/django-cryptography/issues/16 but i got this error:
AttributeError: module 'django.db.models' has no attribute 'DecimalFieldChoices'. Any suggestion